# how can I install exe files on xbox one?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ftp, xbox-one

Is there a way to install via exes on an XBOX one?
I would like to install filezilla server. 
I have searched the app store and found no ftp servers.
I have tried running the filezilla ftp server exe, but XBOX ONE says it cannot run exes. I have also googled this.

are there any solutions? I want to browse the xbox one for the minecraft app data folder, and upload skins I made. Its my understanding xbox one is a moded windows10. How can i make it work? how can I install the programs I want on XBOX one?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The XBox One is a gaming console, not a desktop computer -- it cannot run Windows applications.

While there are some *architectural* similarities between the console's operating system and Windows 10, these similarities are not relevant to you as an end user.

Comment: ms says its a derivative of windows 10, what does that mean?

Comment: In practical terms, for you? Nothing. It's a statement about how the operating system was designed, not about how you can use it.